# Is there any way that allow us to achieve asynchronous operation other than callback function?

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, callback, asynccallback

The main thread tells the system to do something, and registers a callback function `handler()`. Then the main thread continue to do some other work. When the task is finished, the system will call `handler()`. The `handler()` and the main thread can run concurrently. This is what I know about callback function.

But I have two questions:

1. In the case above, the `handler()` will respond to the result of the task and finish the rest of the work. What if we want the main thread to respond to the completion of the task but still can do some other work before the task is completed, can we do that?
2. Is there any other techniques that we could use to achieve asynchronous operations other than callback function?

Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async), for one. There are lots of synchronization techniques in C++.

Comment: Thank you. It's not limited to any language. I actually want to ask about the underlying principles. @PeteBecker

Comment: **Answer for topic:** No because thread is  asynchronous operation primitive (other asynchronous operations are implement on this) is require callback anyway.
**Answer for 1:** There is way but hard to explain. It depend on your program design. what you need it similar to [task system](https://sean-parent.stlab.cc/presentations/2017-01-18-concurrency/2017-01-18-concurrency.pdf).
**Answer for 2:** No because of my 1st answer but you can implement your own mechanism to hide callback.

Comment: C++20 coroutines.

Comment: FYI, "callback" is _any_ function of yours that is called by a library that your code uses. There can be callbacks even in a single-threaded, completely synchronous application.

Comment: @Ryan — if you don’t want C++ answers don’t tag the question C++.

Comment: "What if we want the main thread to respond to the completion of the task but still can do some other work before the task is completed, can we do that?" - In programming you could do almost anything. But this would require language-specific things. Without language specification your questions cannot be answered.